# How do I create multiple bundles with gulp-browserify?

Tags: browserify, blanket.js

I'm trying to use [blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/) to measure test coverage of my browserified library, and the coverage numbers aren't making much sense since I'm including `jQuery`, `lodash`, `es5-shim`, and `x-tag-core.js` in the bundle.

I would like to create multiple bundles, as described in the [browserify documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles), but from `gulp` instead of the command line. Essentially I would like to do something like Sebastian Deutch [describes](http://9elements.com/io/index.php/external-bundles-with-browserify-and-gulp/), except without the the concatenation step at the end (he's doing separate bundles to shorten compile times).

Can anyone point me to an example of how to do this? (or a better way of doing code coverage..?)

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md

Comment: That looks like a better way to shorten compile times, however it doesn't solve my test coverage problem.  `blanket.js` uses a `data-cover` attribute on the script tag to know where to apply coverage, and when `jQuery` et.al. is contained in the browserify bundle my coverage plummets since I'm obviously not covering all of `jQuery`..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of trial-and-error, and after abandoning the `gulp-browserify` plugin (it's black-listed, but examples of using `browserify` directly in gulp are hard to come by), I managed to get this working. The salient parts of my `gulpfile.js` are (I'm not sure at all what the `source` calls do):

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    clean = require('gulp-rimraf'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify:externals', function () {
    var vendor = browserify(['jquery', 'es5-shim', 'lodash']);
    vendor.require('jquery');
    vendor.require('lodash', {expose: '_'});
    vendor.require('es5-shim');
    return vendor.bundle()
        .pipe(source("not-used-but-needed-string.js"))
        .pipe(rename('external.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});

gulp.task('browserify', ['browserify:externals'], function () {
    var app = browserify('./index.js');
    app.external('jquery');
    app.external('es5-shim');
    app.require('./index.js', {expose: 'maxby'});
    return app.bundle()
        .pipe(source("not-used-but-needed-string.js"))
        .pipe(rename('maxby.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
        .on('error', gutil.log);
});
```

I've also created a [repository](https://github.com/thebjorn/browserify-vendor-example) with a complete, but minimal example (I'm quite new at this so any corrections are much appreciated).